# GKE Ingress with Multiple Backend Services returns 404

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to create a GKE Ingress that points to two different backend services based on path. I've seen a few posts explaining this is only possible with an nginx Ingress because gke ingress doesn't support rewrite-target. However, this Google documentation, [GKE Ingresss - Multiple backend services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services), seems to imply otherwise. I've followed the steps in the docs but haven't had any success. Only the service that is available on the path prefix of `/` is returned. Any other path prefix, like `/v2`, returns a 404 Not found.

Details of my setup are below. Is there an obvious error here -- is the Google documentation incorrect and this is only possible using nginx ingress?

```
-- Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: app-static-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: app-managed-cert
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /v2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-2-service
            port:
              number: 8080

-- Service 1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5000

-- Service 2
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-2-service
  labels:
    app: api-2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api-2
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 5000
```

Comment: Could you also share your deployment without Private information? GCP ingress should supports multiple endpoints, I guess its misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP Ingress supports multiple paths. This is also well described in [Setting up HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer). For my test I've used both Hello-world v1 and v2.

There are 3 possible issues.

- Issue is with container ports opened. You can check it using netstat:

```
$ kk exec -ti first-55bb869fb8-76nvq -c container -- bin/sh
/ # netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/hello-app
```

- Issue might be also caused by the `Firewall` configuration. Make sure you have proper settings. (In general, in the new cluster I didn't need to add anything but if you have more stuff and have specific Firewall configurations it might block).
- Misconfiguration between `port`, `containerPort` and `targetPort`.

Below my example:

**1st deployment with**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: first
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: container
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 8080
```

**2nd deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: second
  labels:
    app: api-2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: container
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-2-service
  labels:
    app: api-2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api-2
  ports:
  - port: 6000
    targetPort: 8080
```

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-service
            port:
              number: 5000
      - path: /v2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-2-service
            port:
              number: 6000
```

**Outputs**:

```
$ curl 35.190.XX.249
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: first-55bb869fb8-76nvq
$ curl 35.190.XX.249/v2
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: second-d7d87c6d8-zv9jr
```

Please keep in mind that you can also use `Nginx Ingress` on GKE by adding specific annotation.

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

Main reason why people use `nginx ingress` on `GKE` is using `rewrite` annotation and possibility to use `ClusterIP` or `NodePort` as serviceType, where `GCP ingress` allows only `NodePort` serviceType.

Additional information you can find in [GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to deploy your example successfully and behind Google's IAP to rule out that issue as well.

In my example, I've modified the v2 API to add a route serving `/v2` and the desired response comes back. This was unexpected because I thought any requests to `/v2` would be routed to that service at it's root. It seems that both services are being made available on the `/` prefix.

Is it expected that each app needs to modify it's code to serve the correct prefix? How would this work when two apis are serving traffic to the root?

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean. In [Ingress doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) for example if you would get http://ip/abcd it would go to `api-service` as it wouldn't match any path so it would go to root path which is `/` and its `api-service`. When typed `http://ip/v2` it matched the path for `api-2-service`. However some applications needs specific URL, in this situation you have to use `rewrite` annotation and you would need to use `nginx ingress`. GCP also support some wildcards `*`. Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: Routes specific to a service don't appear to work. The Google `hello-app` serves the same response on any route you hit (ex: `/`, `/randomroute` serve the same thing).

If you extend the `hello-app` to have a few more routes, such as `/login`, I would expect that traffic is routed to that endpoint appropriately.

For example: `/v2/login` should show the `/login` route.

However, adding any additional routes to the hello-app example will only return the `/` response.

Comment: GCP Ingress allows to use path but in very basic way. GCP Ingress requires 1:1 match, if you would like use `/v2/login` you would need to create specific path for `/v2/login`. In your example `/v2/login` should show the `/login` route, you would need to use `Nginx Ingress` with `rewrite` annotation. More details about `Nginx Ingress` patch you can find [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)