# Ingress manifest with same host but different paths

Tags: kubernetes, routes, annotations, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've encountered an odd problem, I think. I'm not sure if my rewrite-target is correct.
I got two URLs that I want to reach, both URLs are going to different backend and frontends. The /login endpoint will be added automatically when you hit the login-page, which we will do.

first one: dev.app.com/login
second one: dev.app.com/path2/login

The first URL is always working, even if I put /login after the host directly or just let it redirect from dev.app.com to dev.app.com/login.

But the second URL is working only if I let it redirect from dev.app.com/path2 to dev.app.com/path2/login. If I put dev.app.com/path2/login directly in the browser I will get an 404 not found nginx error. The same goes if I first put dev.app.com/path2/ and gets redirected to dev.app.com/path2/login (which works), then I reload the page. Then I get an 404 not found error.

I have setup an Ingress file with the following code:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-fe
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - dev.app.com
      secretName: tls-secret-con
  rules:
    - host: dev.app.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: path1svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /path2(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: path2svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Yaml Can you change the PathType to Prefix and have a check?. Can you refer to this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257667/gke-ingress-with-multiple-backend-services-returns-404?rq=1) and [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) and Let me know if this resolves your issue. Find sample examples for  [ingress Path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/%E2%80%A6).

Here's the example from the Kubernetes docs:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo/bar
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /foo/bar/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we managed so solve it. 

Was the static files path that was incorrect